# Sort array of strings without converting them into integer

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

I have an array of strings expressing integer values:

```
array = ["0934", "123", "934", "0123"]
```

I want to sort the array without converting the strings into integers.
The expected output is:

```
array = ["0123", "123", "0934", "934"]
```

Please suggest how I can do that.

Comment: Considering that `"0123".to_i #=> 123` and `"123".to_i #=> 123`, why does your "expected output" have `"0123"` preceding `"123"`?

Comment: What is the logic behind your sorting?

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. I think you might mean the following: "I want to sort the array of strings (in place) so that if the elements of the resulting array were converted to integers they would be in [numerical order](https://www.reference.com/math/meaning-numerical-order-7099285d76ee357b), but I do not want to convert the strings to integers in the sort operation".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot convert a string to an integer within [Array#sort_by!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21)'s block, you could pad the strings to the left with zeroes (using [String#rjust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-rjust)) so they are all the same length, then sort on those padded strings.

```
n = array.map(&:size).max
  #=> 4
array.sort_by! { |s| s.rjust(n, '0') }
  #=> ["123", "0123", "0934", "934"]
```

Note

```
array.map { |s| s.rjust(n, '0') }
  #=> ["0934", "0123", "0934", "0123"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick

```
array.sort_by!(&:to_i)
```

Comment: But, I dont want to convert it to integer.

Comment: You have to convert it into integer to compare the values and sort

Comment: @Pramod That is what requirement is. I can't.

Comment: If a = ["1", "5", "10", "50"], a.sort = ["1", "10", "5", "50"], a.sort_by!(&:to_i) = ["1", "5", "10", "50"]

Comment: @ChiragAgrawal : Just to make it clear. This does not convert the array to integers. It just uses temporary integers to sort the array, and sorts the array in place. Array isn't converted to an integer array.

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as this:

```
array.sort
# => ["0123", "0934", "123", "934"]
```

By the way, your expected answer is wrong.

**Edit**

Okay, I think I finally got your intention. That is, you wanted the array to be sorted by the values yielded by reading the elements as floats, and then by the descending order of their length.

```
array.sort_by{|e| [e.to_f, -e.length]}
# => ["0123", "123", "0934", "934"]
```

Come on, you needed to write so in the question from the first place. Don't expect that many people can arrive at such non-trivial requirements by reading between the lines.

Comment: Please check the question again, as the expected output is
["0123", "123", "0934", "934"]

Comment: I think the OP wants the sorted strings `s` to be in `s.to_i` order, but does not want to convert the strings to integers in the sort operation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That contradicts with the claim that the OP does not want to convert to integers.

Comment: @ChiragAgrawal No, I won't check it again. I have checked it so many times already. As I wrote, your expected output is wrong. Otherwise, write your logic behind sorting.